# use odata or MVC to return json?

Tags: ajax, json, odata

I am trying to use ajax to do CRUD.  Should I use ODATA or MVC?  i am also planning to use json in mobile platform as well.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat subjective - but the two key things with ODATA are that a) huge amounts of heavy lifting is done for you at the server end and b) that there are also libraries to help at the client end. Downside is that you have to do what it does although since you're pointing it at entities that can be quite complex and is flexible.

With MVC you have to do all your own work but in return you get exactly what you need.

All other things being equal, I'd probably start with ODATA...